# Connecting Large Copper Pipe To PEX With Sharkbyte

Tags: plumbing, pex, copper, copper-tubing, copper-pipe

I have some 4-6 inch copper piping that I need to replace a portion of.

I have looked and can go copper to pex no problem. But is is it possible to go from 4-6 inch copper to PEX? There is a significant size difference between the two, so I wasn't sure if this was acceptable or not.

Let me also add that the 5 inch copper gets reduced to a 1/2 copper, and has a tee connector, that continues to run to my water heater. Now I had to cap the tee last night as it was leaking, but when I remove the cap there will not be enough copper pipe to work with, so I'll have to replace a whole section.

Comment: Go shopping. Shopping is off topic here. I'll bet a stale doughnut sharkbites are not made in that size, so that's not going to happen, but I'm not going shopping for you to confirm that. Either you find the fittings you need, or you find the fittings you need are not made in the type of fitting you want and you'll have to do **real plumbing** or hire a real plumber to do that for you.

Comment: @Ecnerwal - by *real plumbing* you mean work with copper?

Comment: I know copper sweat (solder or braze) fittings in those sizes exist, because I've used them. You're on the supply side, so rubber couplings are not an option. Copper press fittings **may** be available, but $$$$ for the tooling. PEX OD **is** Copper tube size, so if you have managed to find PEX that large (3" is as big as I've ever found) the diameter would be the same. Otherwise you'll need reducers that attach to 5" copper, and "appeals to homeowners that don't do soldering" fittings are unlikely to be available in that size range.

Comment: I wouldn't trust a push connector for pipe that huge anyway.

Comment: Recommended set-up then is to stick with copper and solder?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding this scenario. Why on earth would a supply be that large? And is it 4, 5, or 6 inch? Why the ambiguity?

Comment: I'll get a pic to post soon - on a work call so can't step away from the computer atm.  The whole set-up is FUBAR - example, seems the entire water line in my crawlspace was re-routed from POINT A to POINT B and this spigot was NOT included in the cut-off for my home, so I had to go to the street and cut the water supply there

Comment: Start with determining the actual size of your pipe, which you seem undecided about as 4, 5, or 6 inches. Then go look for fitting options, which will probably turn out to be  solder. Then ask yourself how good you are at a really quite challenging soldering task, and whether paying a plumber might be the better part of valor here. Soldering 1/2" is easy. Soldering 4" and up is a challenge, and takes a serious torch as well as some skill.

Comment: If soldering is the only route I can go - I def need to call a plumber.  I've never done soldering a day in my life, and with this being the main supply coming into my home I DON'T WANT TO RISK a screw-up.  I've cut copper and replaced with a sharkbyte to cpvc before no issues - but due to sizes it doesn't seem this is an option here.

Comment: I think @Ecnerwal has expressed my questions rather well, but just to pile on .. :) ... WHY do you have 5 inch supply pipes?   This is a residential DIY forum.  If you have something highly unusual  you need to describe it a lot better, include pictures, include more info about why you are doing this.  Otherwise my instinctive answer would be to just rip out and replace ALL your unusually large piping.  If you're working in the basement of a large apartment building or such, on the common supply, this forum is not for you.

Comment: 5" copper supply pipe is totally bizarre - that's larger than any DWV I've seen - would like to see details of this story.

Comment: Are you mixing up length vs diameter? Diameter is the only part that matters for fitting size. A 4 inch supply that reduces to 1/2 inch makes no sense.